# How to stop a page refresh in angular 2 within aspx

Tags: asp.net, angular, pagemethods

The pagemethod works, however when I use the webmethod it refreshes the page destroying the reason to use angular 2 in the first place.

How do I prevent the form from refreshing the page?

index.aspx

```
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMain"
                            runat="server"
                            EnablePageMethods="true" >
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </form>
  </body>
```

index.aspx.cs

```
  [WebMethod]
  public static string getString()
  {
      return "Test";
  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <Button (click)="btnSubmit_Click">test</Button>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
btnSubmit_Click()
{
    var test = window['PageMethods'].getString(this.onSucces, this.onError);
}
```

note:

At this moment I'm trying to use angular 2 with aspx for the company if it works it might become a standaard for small frontend api's and since its quite limited on information I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make button `type` as `button`, because by default button `type` is `submit`. `button` with type `submit` may lead to post back a page.

```
<div>
    <Button type="button" (click)="btnSubmit_Click()">test</Button>
</div>
```