# Embedding an Angular app inside .net ASPX page with master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing, angular4-router

I've an ASP.NET Web application with master page containing a **header**, **tabs**, **BodyContent**(each page content goes here), **footer** place holders for user controls (header, tabs, footer) and page content (MainContent). The Tabs user control has unordered list of tabs, for example let's consider Tab's text as **TabOne**, **TabTwo**, **TabFour**, One click of each tab respective webpage loads with the help a javascript function with below line of code:

```
window.location.href = "TabOne.aspx";
```

Now I got a new request to add a tab **TabThree** to load an angular page showing Header, tabs, footer and the BodyContent holding the content of angular application i.e., on click of **TabThree**, I've to load an angular application in existing ASP.NET web application similar to the reference link([How to include external Angular 2 app in ASP.NET Webforms aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271792/how-to-include-external-angular-2-app-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-page))

```
//TabThree.aspx
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Base.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Programs.Default" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Base.Master" %>


<asp:Content ID="Header" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">
<%--<base href="/AngularComponents/">--%> //No difference with uncommenting the base href
<%--<base href="/">--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Tabs.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Tab" ContentPlaceHolderID="Tab" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent"   runat="server">

<div id="pageContent">
   <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="AngularModules/inline.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="AngularModules/main.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="AngularModules/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="AngularModules/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
   <link href="AngularModules/styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </div> 
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Footer" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

If I run the angular application independently it launches fine with **ng serve -o** command and it comes up fine at the URL (http://localhost:4200/#/TabThree?id=TID100). Now I've copied the **dist** folder to the ASP.NET Web application workspace and renamed it as **AngularModules**, On click of **TabThree** I've tried to load the angular component into Bodycontent with one of the below line of code for navigation:

```
window.location.href = "TabThree.aspx/#/TabThree?ID=TID100";

window.location.href = "TabThree.aspx?AngularComponents/#/TabThree?ID=TID100";
```

The Head content loads fine but the Bodycontent which supposed to load Angular component of **TabThree** is blank with the console error logged as below:

```
ERROR Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
"ERROR"
{
  [functions]: ,
  __ proto __: { },
  __zone_symbol__currentTask: { },
  description: "Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.",
  message: "Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.",
  name: "Sys.ParameterCountException",
  stack: "Sys.ParameterCountException: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
  at String$startsWith (http://localhost:62557/ScriptResource.axd?

  d=gb2H0hcR0_2oXWpLxJmdTg2S_j-8tZAZO1r6sTjByVD4-_6_cs99E6CayZY9pi0-N-ip5bmZNlhZWaB-IG2xnFZG-NKKnY8LqkMvfx1uzDhC1zqaP8PQi4JB24Hq7urD6rwOMv6ZCQbxzc19pQ0mcl6iexnSPre_a0zN-jpBGmFTlZ5rxoZ47qCy4shfjh4T0&t=ffffffff87bbe9c7:494:12)
  at startsWith
```

I referred the link ([Including an Angular2 application to Asp.Net Webforms Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42562240/including-an-angular2-application-to-asp-net-webforms-page)) but that too didn't solve the problem and I'm not able to launch the Angular component as a Tab in the BodyContent placeholder.

I've studied both the reference links but they don't have the right information about how the routing/navigation is happening to load the angular component in the ASPX Page.

I've tried other approaches than mentioned above which redirects the entire page and launch Angular application as a standalone but my requirement is to inscribe the angular component into the **Bodycontent** of the **TabThree.aspx** page so it would be consistent with the other Tabs/pages.

Any help in solving this **Routing issue** in the hybrid application would be a great help and I would appreciate the same.

Thanks in Advance!!

I didn't find any possible duplicate for the same and I've linked the references as well, Hopefully this is not marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed with the help of IFrame in the aspx page.

//TabThree.aspx

```
<div id="dvngComponent" runat="server"></div>
```

//TabThree.aspx.cs

```
string url = "AngularComponents/#/TabThree?ID=TID100";

HtmlGenericControl ngComponent = new HtmlGenericControl("iframe");
ngComponent.Attributes.Add("id", "frmNgComponent");
ngComponent.Attributes.Add("src", url);
ngComponent.Attributes.Add("allowtransparency", "true");
ngComponent.Attributes.Add("frameBorder", "0");
ngComponent.Style["margin"] = "0 0 0 0";
ngComponent.Style["width"] = "100%";
ngComponent.Attributes.Add("height", "300px");
dvngComponent.Controls.Add(ngComponent);
```